# How do you define an anonymous function in lambda calculus terms (or how can I say some language supports anonymous functions)?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda, computer-science

Does java support in current version of 6 lambda expressions or "anonymous functions"? Is there something I can't do in java that I couldn't do with a programming language supporting lambda expressions? I understand that java is turing complete so you can do "anything" in it.

Why couldn't anonymous inner class wrapped functions represent functions as defined in lambda calculus?

What actually is an anonymous function and how you can say that some language supports anonymous functions?

Comment: Could you please define "support"? Otherwise, the question is meaningless.

Comment: Good question, I would say that haskell supports anonymous functions because I can almost use formal lambda calculus syntax to define my anonymous functions and compose them. For java I'm not so sure because I can emulate lambdas (to some extent?) with inner classes that achieve similar results. By similar results I mean that I can create and compose "functions" even if it is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I already hinted at with my comment above, the question really hinges on how exactly you define "support". In your question you already mentioned that Java is Turing-complete, and thus Java "supports" (for some definition of "supports") everything that every other programming language supports.

Java *does* support anonymous functions: just write an interpreter for the λ-calculus in Java and pass the anonymous function in as a string.

However, I for one find that too much work for using an anonymous function. So, for me the interesting question is not so much whether Java supports anonymous functions but whether, when I want to use anonymous functions, Java supports *me*. IOW: does Java make it easy to use anonymous functions, does it guide me, does it help me?

Let's make a simple experiment: implement the `map` function and use it to increment every element of the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` by `1`.

### Haskell

Here's how the implementation of `morph` (which is what I'm going to call the function in order to not collide with the already existing builtin `map` function) looks like in Haskell:

```
morph _ []     = []
morph f (x:xs) = f x : morph f xs
```

That's all. Short and sweet: morphing the empty list with anything is just the empty list, and morphing a list with at least one element is applying the morphing function to the first element and concatenating that with the result of morphing the rest of the list.

As you can see, writing a function which accepts a function as an argument, is very easy, very lightweight.

Assuming that we have a list `l`:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

We can now call morph like so:

```
morph (\x -> 1 + x) l
```

Again, *passing* an anonymous function to our higher-order function is very easy, very lightweight.

And it looks almost like λ-calculus. In fact, if you use a Haskell IDE, a text editor with a Haskell mode or a Haskell pretty-printer, it will actually be displayed like this:

```
morph (λx → 1 + x) l
```

It gets even easier if we use an *operator section*, which allows us to pass a partially applied operator:

```
morph (1+) l
```

Or, we can pass the pre-defined `succ` function which returns the successor of an integer:

```
morph succ l
```

Although this is of course not an anonymous function, it is a named one.

### Scala

In Scala, it looks very similar. The main difference is that Scala's type system is more complex than Haskell's and thus requires more type annotations:

```
def morph[A, B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = l match {
  case Nil     => Nil
  case x :: xs => f(x) :: morph(xs)(f)
}
```

It is still very lightweight. Essentially, all we had to do was to declare the `f` parameter to be of type `A => B` (i.e. a function from type `A` to type `B`), which is actually syntactic sugar for `Function1[A, B]`.

Now we just need our list:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

And morph it:

```
morph(l) {_ + 1}
```

This takes again advantage of some of Scala's syntactic sugar. In anonymous functions, you can leave off the parameter list; if use every parameter exactly once and in the order they are defined, you can simply refer to them as `_`.

But even the full form is not much heavier:

```
morph(l) {(e) => e + 1}
```

If I had gone through the trouble of making `morph` an instance method of some class and defined an implicit conversion from `List` to that class according to the *Pimp My Library* pattern, I could have even written something like

```
l morph {_ + 1}
```

### Scheme

Scheme, of course, should have no problems with anonymous and higher-order functions. Here's `morph`:

```
(define (morph f l)
    (if (null? l)
        null
        (cons
            (f (first l))
            (morph f (rest l)))))
```

Here's our list:

```
(define l '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

And our anonymous function usage:

```
(morph (lambda (e) (+ e 1)) '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

### Ruby

```
module Enumerable
  def morph
    [].tap {|r| each {|e| r << yield(e) }}
  end
end
```

This is *extremely* lightweight. We didn't even have to define a parameter for the function, because in Ruby, every method has an implied function parameter, called a *block*.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Calling it is almost as lightweight as Scala

```
l.morph {|e| e + 1 }
```

I can sort-of replicate the operator sections from the Haskell example by grabbing a reference to the `+` method of `1`:

```
l.morph(&1.method(:+))
```

Ruby also has a pre-defined `succ` method for integers which we can pass using the `Symbol#to_proc` trick:

```
l.morph(&:succ)
```

Some people criticize blocks in Ruby, because every method can only take a single block, and methods taking more than one function are much uglier, but it's actually not *that* bad. Here's the same code as above, but without using blocks:

```
module Enumerable
  def morph(f)
    [].tap &-> r { each &-> e { r << f.(e) }}
  end
end

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

l.morph -> e { e + 1 }
l.morph(1.method(:+))
```

### ECMAScript (pre-2015)

ECMAScript is a direct descendant of Scheme, so it's no surprise that it can handle our problem nicely, although with some amount of syntax clutter:

```
Array.prototype.morph = function (f) {
    var r = [];
    this.forEach(function (e) { r.push(f(e)); });

    return r;
}
```

The main distraction here is the generally ugly syntax, not so much the handling of higher-order functions.

Let's build our list (well, array):

```
var l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And call the `morph` function (actually, a method in this case) passing an anonymous function as an argument:

```
l.morph(function (e) { return e + 1; });
```

### ECMAScript (post-2015)

ECMAScript 2015 introduced *"fat arrow" anonymous function literals*:

```
Array.prototype.morph = f => {
    const r = [];
    this.forEach(e => r.push(f(e)));

    return r;
}
```

Let's build our list (well, array):

```
const l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And call the `morph` function (actually, a method in this case) passing an anonymous function as an argument:

```
l.morph(e => e + 1);
```

### C#

Now we're moving closer to our ultimate target language. Here's C#:

```
public static IEnumerable<B> Morph<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> l, Func<A, B> f)
{
    IList<B> r = new List<B>();
    foreach (var e in l) r.Add(f(e));

    return r;
}
```

Not too bad. Note the type of the function: `Func<A, B>`. This is a pre-defined type which is part of the core library, just like `Function1[A, B]` in Scala or `a → b` in Haskell. (This is an important distinction to Java.)

Thanks to type inference and collection initializers, creating the list isn't all too painful:

```
var l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

And passing a lambda which consists only of a single expression is basically as lightweight as Ruby, Scala, Scheme or Haskell and even more lightweight than ECMAScript, because you don't need the `function` or `return` keywords:

```
l.Morph(e => e + 1);
```

But even using the "full" syntax isn't too bad:

```
l.Morph((e) => { return e + 1; });
```

(You'll notice that I made `Morph` an extension method, which means I can call it like `l.Morph(f)` in addition to `Morph(l, f)`.)

### Java (pre-8)

```
static <A, B> List<B> morph(List<A> l, Function1<A, B> f) {
    List<B> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for (A e: l) r.add(f.apply(e));

    return r;
}
```

At first glance, this isn't too bad, actually. In fact, it looks pretty much exactly like the C# version. But why can't I write `f(e)`? Why do I have to write `f.apply(e)`? In all other languages I could use the same (or in the case of Ruby, almost the same) syntax for calling a function that was passed as an argument as I would for calling any other function, procedure or method.

I know it isn't much, but it leaves this kind of bitter taste that somehow functions aren't quite first-class. Also, as we'll see further on, there is one of those small annoyances at every single step along the way, and even though every single one of them is insignificant by itself, they *do* add up.

Here's our list:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

And this is how we call our `morph`:

```
morph(l, new Function1<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer apply(Integer n) {
        return n + 1;
    }
});
```

This is pretty heavy stuff. I mean, all I'm doing is calling a method and passing two arguments. Why does that explode into four lines? In all other languages it was just a simple one-liner. Of course, I could remove all line breaks and it would still be valid:

```
morph(l, new Function1<Integer, Integer>() { @OVerride public Integer apply(Integer n) { return n + 1; }});
```

But I think you see what I'm getting at. The actual operation that is being performed, incrementing each element by 1, is pretty much invisible between all that noise.

Note also that in some of the other languages I actually used anonymous functions *inside* the definition of the `morph` function, for example in Ruby and ECMAScript and it was no big deal. If I were to do that in Java, it would lead to even more clutter and cruft and an explosion of lines.

So, even at this point we are seeing that working with higher-order and anonymous functions in Java is *way* more cumbersome than in pretty much any other mainstream (and not so mainstream) language.

But we haven't even gotten to the really ugly part yet: what is that `Function1<A, B>` type there? Where did that come from?

Well, I actually had to *write* that type *myself*!

```
interface Function1<A, B> {
    B apply(A a);
}
```

This is, of course, a so-called *SAM interface*, i.e. an interface or an abstract class with a *Single 
Abstract Method*. Which is the closest thing to a function type Java has. In some sense, a function *is* just an object with a single method, so that's perfectly fine. The fact that function types are represented via SAM interfaces isn't the problem either. In fact, that's basically how they are are represented in Scala (in Scala, `f(a)` is just syntactic sugar for `f.apply(a)`, so *any* object with an `apply` method is essentially a function), Ruby (in Ruby, `f.(a)` is just syntactic sugar for `f.call(a)`, so *every* object with a `call` method is essentially a function) and similarly in C#.

The problem is that I had to write it, that it wasn't already there.

Not only did I have to *write* it myself, I had to come up with a *name* for it. *And* I had to come up with a name for the method. None of which I had to do with any of the other languages here. Well, actually, I just stole the names from Scala, so the actual "coming up with the names" part wasn't so difficult.

What's really important are the *implications* of having to come up with a name. Java has a *nominal type system*, i.e. a type system based on *names*. And thus the fact that I had to come up with a name myself means that everybody else also has to come up with names. And because *their* names are different than mine (and if they aren't, then that will be a compile error), that means that I cannot pass the same function to two different libraries. Say, for example, I want to pass the same filtering function to my gridview and to my ORM. But the gridview expects, say, a `javax.swing.Predicate<T>` with a single method `apply(T el)` whereas my ORM expects an `org.sleepy.Predicate<T>` with a single method `apply(T el)`.

Note that these two types are really exactly the same, it's just that they have different names and thus I cannot pass the same function to both libraries. This is not a hypothetical example. During the recent discussions about Project Lambda for Java, someone counted how many duplicate instances of a `Predicate` type there were already in Java SE 6, and IIRC the number was in the double digits.

It is perfectly possible to solve this problem in a nominal type system. After all, there aren't dozens of incompatible copies of a `List` type, simply because Sun put a *single* one in the library, and everybody uses that. They could have done the same with `Function`, but they didn't, which leads to a proliferation of identical, yet mutually incompatible types not only in third-party libraries but even *within* the JRE. (For example, `Runnable` is arguably a function type, as is `Comparator`. But why do they have to be special-cased?) In .NET, it works just fine, because Microsoft put one single type into the runtime. (Well, actually not quite one single type, but close enough.)

*Because* there is no single function type in the JRE, there are also only very few methods which take a function type. This is another thing that makes first-class and anonymous functions hard to use in Java. Once you have one, there's not much you can do with it. You can't filter an array with a predicate function, you can't transform a list using a mapping function, you can't sort a gridview using a comparator function.

This is also one of the reasons why I am so disappointed with some of the iterations of Project Lambda. They keep dropping the introduction of Function Types from the project, although the lack of function types is IMHO one of the biggest problems. The ugly syntax can be fixed with IDE trickery, the lack of standard function types can't. (Not to mention all those people who use the JVM and the JRE but don't use Java. They don't benefit one bit from adding syntactic sugar for anonymous inner SAM classes to the Java language, simply because they *do not use* the Java language. What they need are function types, and an updated collection library which *uses* function types.)

So, we're up to four problems now:

1. *syntactic overhead* because you have to use stuff like `f.apply(a)` and `new Function1<A, A>() { public A apply(A a) { return a; }}` (BTW, that's the identity function, i.e. the function which does absolutely nothing, and it takes up 58(!) characters),
2. *modelling overhead* because you have to define your own function types yourself, in addition to the domain types you actually care about,
3. *limited usefulness* because once you have created your lambdas, there aren't actually that many methods which take lambdas as arguments and
4. *limited reuse* because even *if* you find a method that takes a lambda, it doesn't take *your* lambda, since the types don't match up.

And when I talk about "modelling overhead", I'm not just talking about *one* `Function1` type. Enter primitive types …

Have you noticed how I used `Integer`s and not `int`s in my code above? Yes, that's right, the single biggest design screwup in the history of programming languages, Java's Original Sin, the bane of every Java programmer's existence, has once again come to bite us in the ass: primitive types.

You see, in Scala, there is exactly *one* class that represents a function with `n` arguments. It's called `FunctionN[T₁, T₂, …, Tn, R]`. So, there is exactly one class `Function0[R]` for functions without any arguments, one class `Function1[T, R]` for functions with one argument, one class `Function3[A, B, C, R]` for functions with three arguments and so forth, all the way up to something around 20, I believe.

In C#, there are exactly *two* classes that represent a function with `n` arguments: `Func<T₁, T₂, …, Tn, R>` and `Action<T₁, T₂, …, Tn>`. This is because there is no type which represents "no type". So, you cannot declare a function which doesn't return anything using C# (`void` is a modifier, not a type), and thus you need a separate type (`Action`) to represent functions that don't return anything. So, you have two classes `Func<R>` and `Action`, which represent functions that don't take any arguments, two classes `Func<T, R>` and `Action<T>` which represent functions of one argument and so forth, again up to circa 20. (In Scala, a function that doesn't return anything simply has the return type `Unit`, so you can just have a `Function2[Int, Int, Unit]`, for example.)

In Java, however, you need 10×9<sup>n</sup> types to represent a function of n arguments. Let me demonstrate that with just *one* argument:

```
interface Action1_T                 { void    apply(T       a); }
interface Action1_byte              { void    apply(byte    a); }
interface Action1_short             { void    apply(short   a); }
interface Action1_int               { void    apply(int     a); }
interface Action1_long              { void    apply(long    a); }
interface Action1_float             { void    apply(float   a); }
interface Action1_double            { void    apply(double  a); }
interface Action1_boolean           { void    apply(boolean a); }
interface Action1_char              { void    apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_T_R             { R       apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_byte          { byte    apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_short         { short   apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_int           { int     apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_long          { long    apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_float         { float   apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_double        { double  apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_boolean       { boolean apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_T_char          { char    apply(T       a); }
interface Function1_byte_R          { R       apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_byte       { byte    apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_short      { short   apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_int        { int     apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_long       { long    apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_float      { float   apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_double     { double  apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_boolean    { boolean apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_byte_char       { char    apply(byte    a); }
interface Function1_short_R         { R       apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_byte      { byte    apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_short     { short   apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_int       { int     apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_long      { long    apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_float     { float   apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_double    { double  apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_boolean   { boolean apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_short_char      { char    apply(short   a); }
interface Function1_int_R           { R       apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_byte        { byte    apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_short       { short   apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_int         { int     apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_long        { long    apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_float       { float   apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_double      { double  apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_boolean     { boolean apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_int_char        { char    apply(int     a); }
interface Function1_long_R          { R       apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_byte       { byte    apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_short      { short   apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_int        { int     apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_long       { long    apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_float      { float   apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_double     { double  apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_boolean    { boolean apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_long_char       { char    apply(long    a); }
interface Function1_float_R         { R       apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_byte      { byte    apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_short     { short   apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_int       { int     apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_long      { long    apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_float     { float   apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_double    { double  apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_boolean   { boolean apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_float_char      { char    apply(float   a); }
interface Function1_double_R        { R       apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_byte     { byte    apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_short    { short   apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_int      { int     apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_long     { long    apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_float    { float   apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_double   { double  apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_boolean  { boolean apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_double_char     { char    apply(double  a); }
interface Function1_boolean_R       { R       apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_byte    { byte    apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_short   { short   apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_int     { int     apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_long    { long    apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_float   { float   apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_double  { double  apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_boolean { boolean apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_boolean_char    { char    apply(boolean a); }
interface Function1_char_R          { R       apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_byte       { byte    apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_short      { short   apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_int        { int     apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_long       { long    apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_float      { float   apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_double     { double  apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_boolean    { boolean apply(char    a); }
interface Function1_char_char       { char    apply(char    a); }
```

That's 90(!) different types just to represent the concept of "something that takes one argument".

And, of course, if I want to write something which takes a function as an argument, I need to have a corresponding number of overloads as well, so if I want to write a method which filters some values based on a predicate, I need 9 overloads of that function which take `Function1_T_boolean`, `Function1_byte_boolean`, `Function1_short_boolean`, `Function1_int_boolean`, `Function1_long_boolean`, `Function1_float_boolean`, `Function1_double_boolean`, `Function1_boolean_boolean` and `Function1_char_boolean`.

(By the way: this still ignores checked exceptions. Technically, we also need 2<sup>n</sup> copies of every single one of those 90 interfaces, where n is the number of different types of checked exceptions that exist in Java.)

So, that's reasons number 5 and 6: a massive explosion in the number of types and correspondingly the number of methods.

If you put all of that together, then I guess you would agree that anonymous inner classes in Java are much more cumbersome than anonymous functions in, well, pretty much every other programming language.

But there's still more!

We haven't even talked about closures yet! While closures are orthogonal to first-class and anonymous functions, they are also one of the most important (and interesting) use cases of anonymous and first-class functions. Inner classes (whether anonymous or not) *are* closures, but as @Jon Skeet already pointed out, they are severely limited.

In conclusion, I would say that No, Java does not support anonymous functions.

### Java (post-11)

Java 8 introduced *target-typed lambda literals* into the language, as well as the notion of a *functional interface*, and some standard library functional interface types, plus a new collection API based on Streams that makes heavy use of functional interfaces. Java 9, 10, and 11 added further standard library functional interface types and expanded Streams. Java 11 added *local variable type inference*.

So, what does *target-typed* mean? It is the answer to the problem I talked about above: since there were no standardized library types for representing functions, everybody invented their own types. Therefore, even if I want to perform the same logic, I have to write a different functions for every API I am using.

If they had simply introduced a set of new function types, e.g.

```
interface Function1_int_int {
    int apply(int x)
}
```

And said that lambda literals expand to instantiations of that function type like this:

```
(int x) -> x + 1
```

is equivalent to

```
new Function1_int_int {
    @Override public int apply(int x) {
        return x + 1;
    }
}
```

Then, you would not be able to use lambdas anywhere, since no existing library takes a `Function1_int_int` as an argument! You would have had to add new overloads to every existing library that has the concept of "taking a piece of code as an argument". This is simply not scalable.

What they did *instead* was to introduce a bit of *structural typing* into Java, where the *names* of the types are irrelevant, and a lambda like this:

```
(int x) -> x + 1
```

can be passed *anywhere* a type of the following form is expected:

```
interface * {
    int *(int *)
}
```

or

```
class * {
    int *(int *) // abstract!
}
```

And it will *automatically* implement the class or interface with the correct name, and automatically implement the method with the correct name.

And not only is this based on structural typing, as opposed to the entire rest of Java's type system which is *nominal*, it is also based on *the context it is used in*, and that is what is meant by "target-typed": the type of the lambda depends not on the lambda itself, but on *what its target is*, i.e. where it is used.

Back to our example:

```
static <A, B> List<B> morph(List<A> l, Function<A, B> f) {
    List<B> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for (var e: l) r.add(f.apply(e));

    return r;
}
```

The only significant difference to Java pre-8 here is that I am using the pre-defined [`java.util.function.Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) functional interface, which means I don't have to write my own.

Here's our list again (same code as before):

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But here, how we call our `morph`, is the major difference. Instead of this:

```
morph(l, new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer apply(Integer n) {
        return n + 1;
    }
});
```

We now have this:

```
morph(l, n -> n + 1);
```

---

Oh, I almost forgot: there was another question somewhere:

> What actually is an anonymous function

That's easy. A function with no name.

> and how you can say that some language supports anonymous functions?

If it makes it easy to work with them.

Java pre-8 doesn't: there is a difference between *supporting* anonymous functions and being able to emulate a subset of the features of anonymous functions by encoding them into anonymous inner SAM classes. Java post-8 is much nicer.

Comment: See Paul and meder. Gotta remember this for the next time I'm trying to explain a Java fanboi that his language is limited, despite being turing complete and OOy and everything :)

Comment: A veritable tour de force that answers any question I have ever had, ever will have and anyone might ever have about programming Lamba calculus.

Answer (score 0):

One important distinction between (say) lambda expressions in C# and anonymous inner classes in Java is that in Java, any local variables referred to in the inner classes are captured by *value* - which is why the variable has to be final. That variable's value is copied into the inner class on construction.

In C#, the variable can be changed by either the lambda expression or other code in the method, and those changes will be seen in both places too.

You can emulate this in Java by wrapping the original variable in a mutable wrapper - e.g. a single element array - and making the *wrapper* variable final. It's a pretty grotty hack though.

The biggest problem with using anonymous inner classes IMO is the sheer verbosity - stating the class you're extending, then the method you're overriding etc.

For more on closures, and particularly comparing Java and C# in this respect, see [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

Comment: I don't see how this is related to my question. Is closures support required so some language could be said to support anonymous functions as in lambda calculus?

Comment: @JtR: It's related to your question because while Java doesn't explicitly support lambda expressions, anonymous inner classes are usually used as the closest that Java has to closure support.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question or provide any hints on how to solve it. I'm grateful for your time to answer but it seems to me more on general blabber about closures support and advertising your articles rather than answering the question.

Comment: @JtR: I've explained the closest Java comes to supporting anonymous functions or closures at the moment. If that's not good enough for you, then I'm afraid you're out of luck... but calling my answer "general blabber" is hardly going to endear you to anyone else who was thinking of answering.

Comment: My choice of words was poor and I'm sorry for that but information about closures don't really again answer the question. I realize that creating a debate in comments isn't very useful for me for finding the answer but I just had to explain why I down voted the answer.

Comment: JtR: But closures and anonymous functions are extremely closely related. If this *doesn't* help you with your question, then maybe you ought to make the question clearer. How is information about closures - and the extent to which they're supported in Java - unrelated to your question?